# swift Vapor - The operation couldn’t be completed. (MySQL.Error error 4.)

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

I am continuously getting this error.

I am confirming that mysql server is running on my MAC machine and I have created a database in mysql server for this project.

> 1. Below is my main.swift

```
import Vapor
import VaporMySQL

let drop = Droplet()

try drop.addProvider(VaporMySQL.Provider.self)

drop.preparations = [Student.self]

let _ = HomeController(drop: drop)

drop.run()
```

> 2. Below is my HomeController.swift

```
import Vapor
import HTTP
import Foundation

final class HomeController {

    var drop: Droplet

    init(drop: Droplet) {
        self.drop = drop

    let studentsGroup = self.drop.grouped("/")
    studentsGroup.get(handler: homePageWithBankList)
    }

    func homePageWithBankList(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

    do {
        var student = Student()
        student.name = "name"
        try student.save()         // Here error raise
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)    // Getting error log here
    }

    return ""

    }
}
```

> 3. Below is my Student.swift model class

```
import Vapor

final class Student: Model {

    var id: Node?
    var exists: Bool = false

    var name: String = ""

    init() {
        self.id = nil
    }

    init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
        id = try node.extract("id")
        name = try node.extract("name")
    }

    public func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
        return try Node(node:[
            "id": id,
            "name": name
            ])
    }

    static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create("student") { student in
            student.id()
            student.string("name")
        }
    }

    static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.delete("student")
    }

}
```

> 4. Below is mysql.json config file

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "admin",
    "database": "studentsDB",
    "port": "3306",
    "encoding": "utf8"
}
```

> 5. Below are my package dependencies

```
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 5),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/mysql-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
    ]
```

> 6. Below is running mysql --version on my MAC

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

> EDIT:- I have this project on GitHub [>>Here<<](https://github.com/AnandSuthar/MySQLapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's a beginner error :)

First, change

```
do {
        var student = Student()
        student.name = "name"
        try student.save()         // Here error raise
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)    // Getting error log here
    }
```

to

```
var student = Student()
student.name = "name"
do {
    try student.save()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

to see what's going wrong

So, you try to use *students* - table but created *student* in your preparation.

Change

```
try database.create("student") { student in } ...
```

to

```
try database.create("students") { student in } ...
```

Otherwise you can specify the tablename inside the declaration of your model with

```
final class Student: Model {
    static var entity = "student"    
    ...
}
```

Always good to have a look at the Documentation

[Vapor Documentation](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/fluent/model.html)

Comment: I have done all changes but still no luck. I have also update that code on GitHub.

Comment: Can you tell us why changing name from 'student' to 'students' will work ?, as I tried with 'students' and it works but after tried with some more table name change it randomly works with some table names but randomly not works with other table name.   This will make me crazy why this happening .   :(. plz help

Comment: Finally using 'static var entity' everything works, It can be good tip if you can explain why this works because in vapor I think most of them come from iOS so we are not aware of this kind of tips. Thanks a lot.